# error in render but not in material preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm making a tablecloth but, when I render it, the texture looks terrible...
I really don't know why, someone can help me?

[image]  [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com/?

Comment: Looks like a wound-up Displacement shader? Can you show us your material tree, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no modifier on the tablecloth as the screenshot shows, I guess you are using *Displacement* in the shader.

//EDIT: Just looked at the screenshot again. Is the tablecloth the selected "Cube.001" object or is it "Cube"? Because the latter has a modifier, is this responsible for the displacement?

For the shader displacement: The problem is, it is an effect which only works in *Cycles* and is only visible in rendering. Since the *Material Preview* is using *Eevee*, it is not possible to view the effect in preview - you have to switch to *Rendered* view.

So in your case you probably cranked up the *Scale* in the *Displacement* node quite high to make it look okay in *Material Preview* - but it just shows faked normals as you would get with a bump map:

[image: bump only]

But as soon as you switch to *Rendered* view in *Cycles*, the real displacement will be visible (at least if the material is set to "Displacement Only" or "Displacement and Bump"). Note that in my example the *Scale* is set to 15 with a *Midlevel* of 0.5 - this means (on an object with applied scale), the displacement of a greyscale texture with values ranging from 0 to 1 will be a displacement of -7.5 to 7.5 m, a *Midlevel* of 0 means the displacement is 0 to 15 m.

[image: real displacement]

Which means, if you want to eyeball how to set your displacement to look good, you have to do it in *Rendered* view. Of course if you are using a height map for something and know real world dimensions for example, you can use them for the *Scale* settings.

Is this is not your problem, you have to give us more information like your shader setup or other things that might be relevant and could somehow displace the mesh. Or upload your file.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't saw that I have this problem with the displacement 